# Carácteres " ' " e " f " aparecem no textbox, como corrigir?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

Estamos utilizando MVC5, coloquei um campo @Html.TextBoxFor uma função Jquery que não permite a inserção de letras, porém sempre que o usuário digita os caracteres " ' " e " f ", eles são inseridos e apagados no ato, os outros caracteres estão ok, nem chegam a serem digitados, o problema são apenas esses.

Segue a minha função:

```
   $(".input-numeric").numeric({
        decimal: 'false',
        negative:'false'
    });
```

Segue o meu input no cshtml:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NumeroLogradouro, new { @class = "form-control input-numeric tam-6" })
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No JavaScript que `'false'` com aspas simples ou `"false"` são strings, e toda string é `FALSE`.

```
$(".input-numeric").numeric({
    decimal: false,
    negative:false
});
```

Aqui tem um material bem didático sobre o assunto: [W3Schools: JavaScript Booleans](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_booleans.asp).

Comment: Boa tarde Thiago, seria legal você explicar esta diferença pro autor né? Espero que entenda isto como uma critica construtiva :) - Recomendo que leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer - *Ser breve é aceitável, mas explicações mais completas são melhores.*

Comment: @Thiago Lunardi, consegui, você tem razão, realmente funciona, porém o " ' " ainda é permitido, o Cigano Morrison Mendez disse que é um bug do pacote Numeric, mas não posso usar o Type="Number" pq o number tem incompatibilidades com o IE9... Obrigado pela ajuda vou tentar bloquear o " ' ".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, dei uma incrementada. Obrigado.

Comment: Thiago ficou bom, mas eu não entendi: *toda string é FALSE*, o que isto quer dizer? Isto não faz sentido, poderia explicar? (ps: Não fui eu quem negativou a sua respostas)

Answer (score 3):

Aparentemente você está usando o pacote [jQuery.Numeric](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Numeric/). Este pacote tem bugs ([veja a seção 'notes'](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/), e veja que realmente o caractere `'` entra em todos os campos). Não usaria ele se estivesse no seu lugar.

Há duas boas alternativas:

- `<input type="number />"`;
- [jQuery.Inputmask](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.InputMask/).

Answer (score 0):

As alterações feitas para a correção do Bug foram:

Dica do Thiago Lunardi: Não aceita mais a letra F, porém continua aceitando o " ' ".

```
$(".input-numeric").numeric({
    decimal: false,
    negative:false
});
```

Jquery Numeric (Antigo): Aceitava o " ' "

```
$.fn.numeric.keypress = function(e)
{
    // get decimal character and determine if negatives are allowed
    var decimal = $.data(this, "numeric.decimal");
    var negative = $.data(this, "numeric.negative");
    var decimalPlaces = $.data(this, "numeric.decimalPlaces");
    // get the key that was pressed
    var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
    // allow enter/return key (only when in an input box)
    if(key == 13 && this.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "input")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(key == 13)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //dont allow #, $, %, '
    else if(key == 35 || key == 36 || key == 37){
        return false;
    }
```

Jquery Numeric (Novo) foi adicionado a tecla 39, agora bloqueia o " ' ":

```
$.fn.numeric.keypress = function(e)
{
    // get decimal character and determine if negatives are allowed
    var decimal = $.data(this, "numeric.decimal");
    var negative = $.data(this, "numeric.negative");
    var decimalPlaces = $.data(this, "numeric.decimalPlaces");
    // get the key that was pressed
    var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
    // allow enter/return key (only when in an input box)
    if(key == 13 && this.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "input")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(key == 13)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //dont allow #, $, %, '
    else if(key == 35 || key == 36 || key == 37 || key == 39){
        return false;
    }
```

Jquery Numeric Control+V (Antigo): Aceitava o Control+V

```
$.fn.numeric.blur = function()
{
    var decimal = $.data(this, "numeric.decimal");
    var callback = $.data(this, "numeric.callback");
    var negative = $.data(this, "numeric.negative");
    var val = this.value;
    if(val !== "")
    {
        var re = new RegExp("^" + (negative?"-?":"") + "\\d+$|^" + (negative?"-?":"") + "\\d*" + decimal + "\\d+$");
        if(!re.exec(val))
        {
            callback.apply(this);
        }
    }
};
```

Jquery Numeric (Novo): Agora bloqueia o Control+V

```
$.fn.numeric.blur = function()
{
    var decimal = $.data(this, "numeric.decimal");
    var callback = $.data(this, "numeric.callback");
    var negative = $.data(this, "numeric.negative");
    var val = this.value;
    if(val !== "")
    {
        var re = new RegExp("^" + (negative?"-?":"") + "\\d+$|^" + (negative?"-?":"") + "\\d*" + decimal + "\\d+$");
        if(!re.exec(val))
        {
            callback.apply(this);
            this.value = "";
        }
    }
};
```